# Virtualbox consuming all of my memory

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, memory-management, memory-leaks

System specs are as follows:

- 62.8GB of RAM
- 1TB of Hard drive space - Samsung 960 Pro M.2
- CPU is an AMD Threadripper 1950x - 16Core
- Running Ubuntu 17.10
- Virtualbox 5.1.34_Ubuntur121010

So I started small, I want to start with running 5 VMs at the same time, so I set them all to have 2 processors, and use 2048MB of RAM. What I am seeing is my headless VMs consuming more than 7 times the memory expected (RES). I have attached a screenshot of 5 of the headless processes running, after most of the RAM is taken up it starts to use the swap, and as you can see, we are getting pretty close to having both RAM and swap being consumed.

On a smaller system using vmware workstation, I seem to stay within the allocated memory space, is there a setting I am missing? This doesn't look like a caching issue, refer to the image attached.

[HTOP image of processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qntq.png)

Since running 5 VMs would force me to reboot the system, I ended up setting it to 3 VMs this is the "ps aux | grep -i headless":

> cuckoo    35092 29.8 18.7 15761556 12357644 ?   Sl   15:36   0:14 
>          /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment win7x64-vm-101 --startvm 684e8e07-80f5-4b54-b44a-176658a2443e --vrde config
>   cuckoo    35210 33.3 18.7 15757460 12357408 ?   Sl   15:36   0:11 
>          /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment win7x64-vm-102 --startvm 5e93a116-7489-4b10-988c-797dd290dcb0 --vrde config
>   cuckoo    35355 66.8 18.7 15749140 12357636 ?   Sl   15:37   0:10 
>          /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment win7x64-vm-103 --startvm faf7fc9b-2448-4ea7-aa65-16eab611dce5 --vrde config

The showvminfo is this:

```
Name: win7x64-vm-101
Groups: /
Guest OS: Windows 7 (64-bit)
UUID: 684e8e07-80f5-4b54-b44a-176658a2443e
Config file: /home/cuckoo/.vmcloak/vms/win7x64-vm-101/win7x64-vm-101.vbox
Snapshot folder: /home/cuckoo/.vmcloak/vms/win7x64-vm-101/Snapshots
Log folder: /home/cuckoo/.vmcloak/vms/win7x64-vm-101/Logs
Hardware UUID: 684e8e07-80f5-4b54-b44a-176658a2443e
Memory size: 2048MB
Page Fusion: off
VRAM size: 16MB
CPU exec cap: 100%    
HPET: off
Chipset: piix3
Firmware: BIOS
Number of CPUs: 2
PAE: on
Long Mode: on
Triple Fault Reset: off
APIC: on
X2APIC: off
CPUID Portability Level: 0
CPUID overrides: None
Boot menu mode: message and menu
Boot Device (1): Floppy
Boot Device (2): DVD
Boot Device (3): HardDisk
Boot Device (4): Not Assigned
ACPI: on
IOAPIC: on
BIOS APIC mode: APIC
Time offset: 0ms
RTC: local time
Hardw. virt.ext: on
Nested Paging: on
Large Pages: off
VT-x VPID: on
VT-x unr. exec.: on
Paravirt. Provider: Default
Effective Paravirt. Provider: HyperV
State: running (since 2018-07-16T20:11:32.340000000)
Monitor count: 1
3D Acceleration: off
2D Video Acceleration: off
Teleporter Enabled: off
Teleporter Port: 0
Teleporter Address: 
Teleporter Password: 
Tracing Enabled: off
Allow Tracing to Access VM: off
Tracing Configuration: 
Autostart Enabled: off
Autostart Delay: 0
Default Frontend: 
Storage Controller Name (0): IDE
Storage Controller Type (0): PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0): 2
Storage Controller Port Count (0): 2
...
```

Comment: Are you positive you have on the amount of memory you believe you have?  Something does not seem right about that value.   Please update your question to include which version of VirtualBox you are running.

Comment: added the version: 5.1.34_Ubuntur121010

Comment: The link in your comment does not work for me.  If it's important, then the information should be contained in the body of your question, instead of a comment.